# Extract items in XML file and convert it to dict in Python

Tags: python, xml

There is a file called core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/centos/hadoop_tmp/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://test:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

How could I get a dict in python like this:

```
{'hadoop.tmp.dir': 'file:/home/centos/hadoop/tmp', 'fs.defaultFS': 'hdfs://test:9000'}
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are multiple approaches to doing this, xmltodict and untangle being some of them. If those don't provide the output you need, you could use any readily-available xml parsing modules for python and then build your own data structure from the output.

Comment: I have tried xmltodict and get this: OrderedDict([(u'configuration', OrderedDict([(u'property', [OrderedDict([(u'name', u'hadoop.tmp.dir'), (u'value', u'file:/home/centos/hadoop_tmp/tmp')]), OrderedDict([(u'name', u'fs.defaultFS'), (u'value', u'hdfs://test:9000')])])]))]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ElementTree python library which can be found here: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Firstly, you will need to pass the .xml file into the ElementTree library

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('core-site.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Once done, you can then start using the `root` object to parse the XML document

```
for property in root.findall('property'):
```

Within this loop, you can start extracting names and values from your properties

```
for entry in root.findall('property'):
    name = entry.find('name').text
    value = entry.find('value').text
    print(name)
    print(value)
```

You want to add this to a dictionary, which should be as simple as

```
configuration = dict()
for entry in root.findall('property'):
    name = entry.find('name').text
    value = entry.find('value').text
    configuration[name] = value
```

Then you should have a dictionary with all your XML configurations inside of it

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('core-site.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
configuration = dict()
for entry in root.findall('property'):
    name = entry.find('name').text
    value = entry.find('value').text
    configuration[name] = value
print(configuration)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The question already has an accepted answer, but since I commented on it, I wanted to give an example of use of the one of the modules I suggested.

```
xml = '''<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/centos/hadoop_tmp/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://test:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>'''

import xmltodict
# Load the xml string into a test object
test = xmltodict.parse(xml)
# Instantiate a temporary dictionary where we will store the parsed data
temp_dict = {}
# Time to parse the resulting structure
for name in test:
    # Check that we have the needed 'property' key before doing any processing on the leaf
    if 'property' in test[name].keys():
        # For each property leaf
        for property in test[name]['property']:
                # If the leaf has the stuff you need to save, print it
                if 'name' in property.keys():
                    print('Found name', property['name'])
                if 'value' in property.keys():
                    print('With value', property['value'])
                # And then save it to the temporary dictionary in the form you need
                # Do note that if you have duplicate "name" strings, only the last "value" will be saved
                temp_dict.update({property['name']: property['value']})

print(temp_dict)
```

And here's the output

> Found name hadoop.tmp.dir
>
> With value file:/home/centos/hadoop_tmp/tmp
>
> Found name fs.defaultFS
>
> With value hdfs://test:9000
>
> {'hadoop.tmp.dir':'file:/home/centos/hadoop_tmp/tmp', 'fs.defaultFS':'hdfs://test:9000'}

Comment: Thanks for your code. It works but there is already an accepted answer :)